# How do i stop a thread in java?

Tags: java

I have a timer thread:

```
Thread updateTimerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                long updatedTime = 0L;
                long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
                timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;//System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;
                int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
                int mins = secs / 60;
                secs = secs % 60;
                int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
                timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                        + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                        + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
                customHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);

                //updateTimerThread.start();
            }
    });
```

I start it like this:

```
updateTimerThread.start();
```

Then to stop it i tried:

```
updateTimerThread.stop();
```

But i see a black line over the work stop.

[image: stop]

My question is if it's fine ? What is this black line over the stop ?
Maybe i need to use something else then stop ?

What i need it to do is when i click to stop it it will pause stay on the time it was getting to and when i will click start again it will start the timer over again.

So maybe i don't need stop maybe somehow to pausing it ?
And when i make start again it will reset it and will start from the beginning ?

Comment: 1. Declare a boolean run "isRunning" in the thread.

2. Make that variable to "true" before run() method.

3. Have condition in run() method : while (isRunning)

4. Make isRunning as false when you want to stop the thread.

Answer (score 1):

Just let it exit the `run()` method once the work you're doing is finished. No need to explicitly stop the thread.